Issues Installing Redmine Plugins: NameError for RedmineExtensions::PatchManager
Hello Stack Overflow Community,
I am facing problems with installing certain plugins in Redmine, including the easy_gantt plugin, and similar issues occur with other plugins as well. Each time I attempt to run the rake task for installation, I encounter a NameError related to RedmineExtensions::PatchManager. Below is the command I used and the error output:
sudo bundle exec rake redmine:plugins NAME=easy_gantt RAILS_ENV=production --trace

** Invoke redmine:plugins (first_time)
** Execute redmine:plugins
** Invoke redmine:plugins:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant RedmineExtensions::PatchManager

RedmineExtensions::PatchManager.register_controller_patch 'QueriesController', 'EasyGantt::QueriesControllerPatch'
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Did you mean?  Pathname

I've tried searching for a solution but haven't found any substantial information addressing this error. It appears to be a missing or misconfigured dependency, or a specific issue with the patching process related to RedmineExtensions.
Does anyone have any insights or solutions for resolving this NameError? Any suggestions or resources would be greatly appreciated!
I tried installing the easy_gantt plugin on Redmine using the command:
bash
Copy code
sudo bundle exec rake redmine:plugins NAME=easy_gantt RAILS_ENV=production --trace

Expected Outcome:
I expected the installation to proceed smoothly without errors, completing the necessary database migrations and plugin integrations
I am using a Bitnami VM
